# Objects have the same ID on production in Django App

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I have project in Python Django. It has three models: Project, Files and Agreement.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    agreement_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    brief_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BRIEF_CHOICES, default='nieuzupelniony')
    agreement_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=AGREEMENT_CHOICES, default='niedostarczona')
    resources_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RESOURCES_CHOICES, default='niedostarczone')
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default='nieoplacone')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Brak wiadomości')
    project_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="project")
    modifications = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='2')
    corrections = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='3')

    def __str__(self):
         return self.project_name

class Files(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="files")
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Agreement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="agreement")
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

In app we have an admin and users. Every user has welcome.html page which display every user project, every user agreement and objects from one additional model which isn't important. When user click on project (user goes to project_detail.html), he can see information about project and there are all files from this project.

```
def panel(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        queryset = Project.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        queryset2 = Invoice.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        queryset3 = Files.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        queryset4 = Agreement.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'projects/welcome.html', {'project': queryset, 'invoice': queryset2, 'files': queryset3, 'agreement': queryset4})
    else:
        return render(request, 'projects/welcome.html')
```

Admin has user_detail.html page, and there are all files and projects and agreements for this user.

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'projects/user_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['invoice'] = Invoice.objects.all()
        context_data['project'] = Project.objects.all()
        context_data['files'] = Files.objects.all()
        context_data['agreement'] = Agreement.objects.all()
        return context_data
```

Here is a part of my template.

```
            <div class="block bg-white rounded shadow-2xl text-indigo-800 m-2 p-4 w-full h-full">
                <p class="text-3xl text-left mb-2 pb-2 border-b">Pliki</p>
                {% for files in files.all %}
                {% if files.user == user %}
                <div class="flex justify-between mb-2 pb-2 border-b pr-32">
                    <a href="{% url 'files.update' pk=files.id %}" class="text-xl font-thin text-indigo-800 hover:text-indigo-600 text-left mb-2">{{files.name}}</a>
                    <p class="text-xl font-thin text-indigo-800 hover:text-indigo-600 text-left mb-2">{{files.project}}</p>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Unfortunetly when I tried (as admin) edit any of file I've got an error:

```
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:    
get() returned more than one Files -- it returned 8!
```

So to each project you can assign file and agreement. I have problem with my database. On my local environment everything is fine. On local SQlite3 every file object has unique ID, unfortunetly on my producton, on phpMyAdmin every object has the same ID = 0. Where I can find error? I tried working with my models and database, unfortunetly I can't find what is going on. So now I cannot update file for my user even by my Django Admin Dashboard, because I've got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have a problem in your template you use `files in files.all` so when you do `files.project` you get more than one

```
{% for files in files.all %}
```

you need to do :

```
{% for file in files.all %}
....
{{file.project}}</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it isn't a problem. Please look at my models, name is Files, and in return its still files. I know I should name it File, but it isn't problem.

In my database every object has the same ID = 0. So I don't have problem only in template but for example in Django Admin Dashboard too.